# Generic type conforms to Sequence with help of opaque type: some IteratorProtocol

Tags: swift, generics, iterator, opaque-types

```
protocol TreeNode: AnyObject {
    associatedtype T
    var value: T { get set }
    var children: [Self] { get }
    init(_ value: T)
}

protocol Tree: Sequence {
    associatedtype Node: TreeNode
    var root: Node? { get set }
}

extension Tree {
    typealias T = Node.T
    
    func makeIterator() -> some IteratorProtocol {
        BFSIterator(startFrom: root)
    }
}
```

This compiles and looks very promising.
But then all of a sudden in Unit Tests line `let sum = tree.reduce(0, +)` cause compilation error:

> Cannot convert value of type '(Int) -> Int' to expected argument type
> '(Int, (some IteratorProtocol).Element) throws -> Int'

Why compiler can't figure out that `(some IteratorProtocol).Element` is indeed `Int`? And how to help it?

Note, that if I make "an old way" (without opaque types):
func makeIterator() -> BFSIterator {
everything compiles and works perfectly.

Update:

```
struct BFSIterator<Node: TreeNode>: IteratorProtocol {
    private var queue: Queue<Node> = []
    
    init(startFrom root: Node?) {
        root.map { queue.push($0) }
    }
    
    mutating func next() -> Node.T? {
        guard let current = queue.pop() else { return nil }
        queue.push(contentsOf: current.children)
        return current.value
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `BFSIterator`?

Comment: @NewDev struct BFSIterator<Node: TreeNode>: IteratorProtocol { mutating func next() -> Node.T? {

Comment: Please add to the question... seems like it's a relevant part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because there's no way in current Swift (5.2) to specify the associated type for an opaque return value. Thus, `some IteratorProtocol` is not enough for the compiler to figure out what kind of values should the `next()` method return.

This limitation of the language forces you to explicitly declare the iterator type if you want to actually use the sequence.